# How to merge rows with condition on time range in PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

Here is my input pyspark dataframe:

| ID | Name | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2022-06-29 20:00:00 | 2022-07-12 20:00:00 |
| 1 | John | 2022-01-02 19:00:00 | 2022-05-18 20:00:00 |
| 2 | Bob | 2021-07-05 20:00:00 | 2021-09-25 20:00:00 |
| 2 | Jack | 2022-04-24 20:00:00 | 2022-06-25 20:00:00 |
| 3 | Mike | 2021-10-31 20:00:00 | 2021-12-11 19:00:00 |

If they have exact same ID and Name, I would like to merge to one row and their start date should take earliest start date and end date should take the latest end date, the output should be like this:

| ID | Name | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2022-01-02 19:00:00 | 2022-07-12 20:00:00 |
| 2 | Bob | 2021-07-05 20:00:00 | 2021-09-25 20:00:00 |
| 2 | Jack | 2022-04-24 20:00:00 | 2022-06-25 20:00:00 |
| 3 | Mike | 2021-10-31 20:00:00 | 2021-12-11 19:00:00 |

John has been merged and his start date updated to 2022-01-02 and end date updated to 2022-07-12 20:00:00.

How can I achieve in pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `groupby` and `F.max` and `F.min` over the required column.

```
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from typing import Iterator, Tuple
import pandas as pd

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)




data1 = [
[1, "John", "2022-06-29 20:00:00",  "2022-07-12 20:00:00" ],
[1, "John", "2022-01-02 19:00:00",  "2022-05-18 20:00:00" ],
[2, "Bob",   "2021-07-05 20:00:00", "2021-09-25 20:00:00" ],
[2, "Jack", "2022-04-24 20:00:00",  "2022-06-25 20:00:00" ],
[3, "Mike", "2021-10-31 20:00:00",  "2021-12-11 19:00:00" ],

      ]

df1Columns = ["ID", "Name", "Start Date",   "End Date"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = df1Columns)


df1.withColumn("Start Date", F.to_timestamp(F.col("Start Date")))
df1.withColumn("End Date", F.to_timestamp(F.col("End Date")))
print("Given dataframe")
df1.show(n=100, truncate=False)


df_new = df1.groupby(F.col("ID"), F.col("Name")).agg(F.min(F.col("Start Date")).alias("Start Date"), F.max(F.col("End Date")).alias("End Date"))
print("Printing final dataframe")
df_new.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
Given dataframe
+---+----+-------------------+-------------------+
|ID |Name|Start Date         |End Date           |
+---+----+-------------------+-------------------+
|1  |John|2022-06-29 20:00:00|2022-07-12 20:00:00|
|1  |John|2022-01-02 19:00:00|2022-05-18 20:00:00|
|2  |Bob |2021-07-05 20:00:00|2021-09-25 20:00:00|
|2  |Jack|2022-04-24 20:00:00|2022-06-25 20:00:00|
|3  |Mike|2021-10-31 20:00:00|2021-12-11 19:00:00|
+---+----+-------------------+-------------------+

Printing final dataframe
+---+----+-------------------+-------------------+
|ID |Name|Start Date         |End Date           |
+---+----+-------------------+-------------------+
|1  |John|2022-01-02 19:00:00|2022-07-12 20:00:00|
|2  |Bob |2021-07-05 20:00:00|2021-09-25 20:00:00|
|2  |Jack|2022-04-24 20:00:00|2022-06-25 20:00:00|
|3  |Mike|2021-10-31 20:00:00|2021-12-11 19:00:00|
+---+----+-------------------+-------------------+
```